# Is there a way to use .apply instead of iterrows when executing an sql insert from a H2o Frame?

Tags: python, sql, h2o

My goal is to export data from a h2o frame to sql.

I receive the following error when using iterrows, and would like to replace it with an .apply function. An example (preferred) or resources regarding exporting data to SQL from a h2o frame would be very much be appreciated.

The code snippet is:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import pyodbc
import h2o
h2o.init()

data = {'COL_1': ['C1 First value', 'C1 Second value'],
        'COL_2': ['C2 First value', 'C2 Second value'],
        'COL_3': ['C3 First value', 'C3 Second value'],
        'COL_4': ['C4 First value', 'C4 Second value'],
        'COL_5': ['C5 First value', 'C5 Second value'],
        'COL_6': ['C6 First value', 'C6 Second value'],
        'COL_7': ['C7 First value', 'C7 Second value'],
        'COL_8': ['C8 First value', 'C8 Second value'],
        'COL_9': ['C9 First value', 'C9 Second value']}

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['COL_1','COL_2','COL_3','COL_4','COL_5','COL_6','COL_7','COL_8','COL_9'])
h2oframe = h2o.H2OFrame(df)

# removed odbcName and serverName
odbcName = 'xxxxxx'
serverName = 'xxxxxxx'

odbcConnection = pyodbc.connect ('Driver={Sql Server};Server='+serverName+';Database='+odbcName+';Trusted_Connection=yes')
cursor = odbcConnection.cursor()

# TempTable has already been created in the database
for index, row in h2oframe.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TempTable (COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4,COL_5,COL_6,COL_7,COL_8,COL_9) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",row.COL_1, row.COL_2, row.COL_3, row.COL_4, row.COL_5, row.COL_6, row.COL_7, row.COL_8, row.COL_9)
odbcConnection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-19764dc050b1> in <module>
----> 1 for index, row in h2oframe.iterrows():
      2     cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TempTable (COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4,COL_5,COL_6,COL_7,COL_8,COL_9) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",row.COL_1, row.COL_2, row.COL_3, row.COL_4, row.COL_5, row.COL_6, row.COL_7, row.COL_8, row.COL_9)
      3 odbcConnection.commit()
      4 cursor.close()

AttributeError: 'H2OFrame' object has no attribute 'iterrows'
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't directly save to a SQL table. But you can save the whole frame as a new Hive table. See [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-munging/downloading-data.html#save-as-a-hive-table).

```
iris_hex = h2o.import_file("iris/iris_wheader.csv")
iris_hex.save_to_hive(
         jdbc_url = "jdbc:hive2://hive-server:10000/default",
         table_name = "airlines",
         format = "parquet",
         table_path = "/user/bob/tables/iris"
)
```

You can also convert it [back to a pandas frame](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/frame.html#h2o.H2OFrame.as_data_frame) `h2oframe.as_data_frame()` then use `iterrows()` (as mentioned in the error `.iterrows()` is not an attribute for H2O).